# Using "keywords=..." to cite a set of references

Tags: bibtex

I am using KBibtex to manage my references. In Kbibtex I can add a parameter called `keywords`.

In my `.bib` file I have two references, which both have the same `keywords`

```
@article{Bob2016,   
 author = {Bob},    
 journal = {gardening},     
 keywords = {ClaimA},   
 pages = {1-10},    
 publisher = {Someone},     
 title = {Bob's advanced gardening},    
 volume = {2},  
 year = {2016}
}

@article{Bob2015,   
 author = {Bob},    
 journal = {gardening},     
 keywords = {ClaimA},   
 pages = {100-101},     
 publisher = {Someone},     
 title = {Bob's gardening},     
 volume = {1},  
 year = {2015}
}
```

Instead of using `\cite{Bob2015,Bob2016}` to cite the references that have `keywords = {ClaimA}` , I would like to tell latex to cite all the references that carry `keywords = {ClaimA}`, so that upon adding a reference that will also be tagged with `ClaimA` latex automatically cites it in this spot.

Is there something like `\cite{keywords={ClaimA}}`